# Clarity about metrics provided by AWS cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks

I am currently working on a project to monitor an EKS cluster using AWS CloudWatch service. I'm having some doubts about the metrics provided by it in Container Insights namespace.

1. What is node_cpu_limit? Docs say that it is the maximum amount of cpu units that can be assigned to any node in the cluster. Why is it a single value for a cluster? How do I interpret this value when my worker nodes have different cpu capacity? Say one has 2vCPU and the other node has 4vCPU.

2.Similar doubt about node_memory_limit. I have 3 worker nodes with two t4g.small and one m5.large. How do I interpret node_memory_limit for this setup? It's value keeps changing with time. It is sometimes about 3-4 , sometimes about 5 and else about 8. How can be this understood in terms of memory capacity of nodes?

3. Docs say that CW provides aggregate metrics for pods. I'm not understanding how it aggregates. I have a deployment with 3 deployment, but the metrics like pod_cpu_utiliation, pod_memory_utilization,etc seems to be given on deployment level only. As the podname used in the cloudwatch for that pod  matches the name of deployment and not of actual pods. Also like there are three replicas of a pod, but a single value of metric is provided for them.
4. I'm also interested in knowing the pod level cpu and memory allocation and usage. But cloudwatch provide only utilisation. On further digging into the docs I found some formulae of how these utilisation are calculated.

pod_cpu_utilization = pod_cpu_usage/node_cpu_limit

pod_memory_utilization = pod_memory_usage/node_memory_limit

Can I use this to get the resources usage metrics of pod? Also the unclear status of the two limit metrics is also an issue for this calculation.

Refered AWS Cloud watch docs